# Passing list of ignored directories to `tree` command

Tags: shell, tree

I'm writing a script in which I need to generate a tree of directories.

How to pass to `tree` a variable with list of directories to ignore? And those directories are with spaces in name.

I tried something like this:

```
tree -o /volume1/web/eb.html -T "List" --charset UTF-8 -C -I "$to_ignore" -P '*pdf' --prune --noreport /volume1/docs
```

Where vaiable `to_ignore` is a list of directories generated somewhere else by script:

```
'dir1|dir2|dir with space|dir4'
```

but that didn't worked. It crashed on dir with space.

Ok, so using quotes around variable helped with crashes but then `tree` prints even those directories that have required pdf files and are on list to ignore. And what's strange if I write those directories to ignore directly in my `tree ...` command than it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Quote your variables:

```
$ tree foo                
foo
├── bar foo
│   └── blah
├── baz
│   └── blah
├── foo
├── foo bar
│   └── blah
└── yada

8 directories, 0 files
$ to_ignore='yada|bar foo|baz'
$ tree foo -I "$to_ignore"    
foo
├── foo
└── foo bar
    └── blah

3 directories, 0 files
```

Comment: With quotes it will not crash but then `tree` returns directories that have required pdf files even if they are on list of directories to ignore